# @OneToOne - Can't persist the second entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

this is my first post and I have a problem with hibernate @OneToOne mapping. I am following this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/) for my first example. So I have two model classes calls User and Profile. Every time, a user do registry, I want to create a new user account with a given info and default profile for the user. But the problem is that my code is only able to generate user account, but not profile. My structure is as following:

```
public class User {

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="profileUser", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Profile profile;
}

public class Profile {

    @Id     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="PROFILE_ID")
    private Long profileId;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User profileUser;
}

@Repository
public UserDao {
public void createUser(User user) {
        currentSession().save(user);
    }
}

@Service 
public UserService {

    @Autowire UserDao dao;    

    @Transactional
    public void createUser(User user) {

        Profile profile = Profile.createInstance();
        profile.setProfileUser(user);


        user.setProfile(profile);
        dao.createUser(user);
    }

}
```

I look at the console and detect that only one query run to persist the account but not the profile. I have no clue where I do wrong.